# write permission

Tags: permissions, user-management, groups

I'm trying to solve a problem about write permission.
I have the user mamuth in the group www-data, i used the command:

```
adduser mamuth www-data
```

Running:

```
cat /etc/group | grep mamuth
```

Results with:

```
adm:x:4:syslog,mamuth
cdrom:x:24:mamuth
sudo:x:27:mamuth
dip:x:30:mamuth
www-data:x:33:mamuth
plugdev:x:46:mamuth
mamuth:x:1000:
lpadmin:x:114:mamuth
sambashare:x:115:mamuth
```

So now when i check the `/var` right permission i have the following result:

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 20 15:20 www
```

I used the command to be sure to have right permission to write everything as mamuth (fed up to use sudo emacs to write in file):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/
```

I don't know what's wrong while I still don't have permission as for example in /var/www/ i'm tryng to use as mamuth user the command:

```
emacs test
```

and typing some text

emacs display the message:

```
Buffer is read-only:  #<buffer toto>
```

Comment: Did you restart the system after you added mamuth to www-data group?

Comment: I've just killed the terminal, not reboot the system.
After a reboot now it's working.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid a reboot? like the "source" command

Comment: @Mamuth it should be sufficient to start a new *login shell* for the user e.g. `su - mamuth` or `su --login mamuth` or (with sudo) `sudo -i -u mamuth`

Comment: Please don't put "SOLVED" in title. The [duplicate] tag is good enough.